# How to add multiple attachments from a column from excel that has any value (file path) in it

Tags: excel, vba, attachment

I am trying to create a VBA code that will be able to tell excel to add multiple attachments from a specific column that has any value (file path) in it.

E.G. My Excel Column BD2:BD2000 contains a list of email attachmments only and I want excel to select all values from cells BD2:BD20000 (If they are not empty, and Which are basically file paths) and attach it as multiple attachments to my outlook email.

However, I can't get this to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()

 Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set emailRng = Worksheets("Workings").Range("BC2:BC2000")
    Set FilepathRng = Worksheets("Workings").Range("BD2:BD2000")


    For Each cl In emailRng
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value

    Next

    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Next

    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ComboBox17.Value
        .CC = sTo
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = TextBox18.Value
        .Body = "Hi there"
        .Attachments.add = FilepathRng


    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Appreciate if anyone would be so kind to help. I'm  new to VBA and I'm trying to find simple solutions for this so I would appreciate any detailed and easy to understand/advice/solutions any one can give.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's a Good idea to add 2000 items in a mail ? Also, what error are you getting in this ?

Comment: @Mikku When I click the button, it just hangs. Nothing happens. However, when I remove the attachment, it works normally.

I am thinking there is something wrong with my code in telling excel to "attach all filled cells in Column BD which are file attachments as multiple file attachments in Outlook"

Edit: also, I edited the code above

Comment: @Nosferato4 what do you have on column BC? do you want to send mails for each cell in that column with the attachment that are on column BD or how is it going to work?

Comment: @Nosferato4 , let us know if it works now or if you are facing nay error.

Comment: @Mikku thanks a lot again! Managed to make it work!

Comment: Accept the answer if it worked for you .. :) @Nosferato4

Comment: Added a tick mark beside the answer ! I think that's how I accept the answer. Do let me know if this is the case.

Comment: Yup That's Right :) @Nosferato4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will attach all the file paths in Range "BC2:BC2000".

## Warning:

It's not a good approach to add that many files in one Email. Your system may hang. To add 2000 files change the range in For Loop accordingly.

```
Private Sub ToggleButton3_Click()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cl As Range
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Set emailRng = Worksheets("Workings").Range("BC2:BC2000")

    For Each cl In emailRng
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value

    Next

    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)

    With OutMail
        .To = ComboBox17.Value
        .CC = sTo
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = TextBox18.Value
        .Body = "Hi there"

        For Each cl In Worksheets("Workings").Range("BD2:BD2000")
            If Len(cl.Value) > 1 Then
            .Attachments.Add cl.Value
            End If
        Next

        .Display

    End With


    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Your loop is adding the 2000 values :P also you can get rid of the `emailRng = ... till sTo = Mid...` there is no need with your code ;)

Comment: Hi Damian, thank you for your advice. the sTo is  for multiple CC recipients; i came across it in another guide

With regards to the 2000 values, I understand from your suggestion on filling an array with my path, but what I am unclear about is where do I insert it?

Sorry if I sound kinda dumb :P VBA Noob here

Comment: True, I was looking at the  `.To` and it's used on the `.CC` As for the adding, just like Mikku's answer, there you put the second loop to add files to the email.

Comment: `code

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail

        .To = ComboBox17.Value
        .CC = sTo
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = TextBox18.Value
        .Body = "Hi there"


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Workings")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BD").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim myFileList(1 To LastRow - 2)
    i = 1
    For Each C In .Range("BD2:BD" & LastRow)
        myFileList(i) = C
        i = i + 1
    Next C
End With

        
    For i = LBound(myFileList) To UBound(myFileList)
        .Attachments.Add myFileList(i)
    Next i
`

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to add spacings on comment, but I added your code right under the " .Body " in my original VBA code.

Now, it does not hang, but there are no attachments.

Am I doing something else wrongly this time? D:

Comment: Also @Mikku Thank you for your code. Yours actually works. But I am trying out to figure out how to combine your code with Damian 's code. Damian one uses a loop but when I add his code in lieu of yours, it does not select the attachment.

Comment: @Damian .. Why do you need Array ? When you can directly put those address in the Mail ?

Comment: @Nosferato4 ... you don't need to add an array as Damian is suggesting. I mean that's not a wrong way of doing it, it's just another approach. You can use my code as it is. Just beware of adding 2000 files as it can hang your system. Also My code is looping through your range and adding attachments.

Comment: @Mikku oh! ok thank you! This is extremely useful.

 Can I ask, if my cells are blank, will VBA still process cells in column BD that are"blanks"? I am just curious - if they actually do that, will it still hang?

Just curious

Comment: @Nosferato4 ... I have added another condition to check for blanks and ignore. Use the amended version.

Comment: @Mikku I just copied my way to do it because in my case the filepath ain't on the workbook... But whatever fits the OP.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fill an array with your paths, like this for example:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Workings")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "BD").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim myFileList(1 To LastRow - 2)
    i = 1
    For Each C In .Range("BD2:BD" & LastRow)
        myFileList(i) = C
        i = i + 1
    Next C
End With
```

Then to add the attachments you need to do like this:

```
    For i = LBound(myFileList) To UBound(myFileList)
        .Attachments.Add myFileList(i)
    Next i
```